# How to exclude specific result of runif()?

Tags: r, function, random

When I want to generate a random number with `runif()` within a specific interval under exclusion of a particular value (e.g. 0.5) I can write this function `ex.runif()` who does the job, but it is hundreds of times slower than the normal `runif()`. Could anyone point me to a better solution?

```
ex.runif <- function(n, excl, min, max) {
  # ex.runif() excludes the specific value 'excl'
  q <- excl
  while (q == excl) {
    q <- runif(n, min = min, max = max)
  } 
  return(q)
}

set.seed(42)
ex.runif(1, .5, .25, .75)  # exclude .5, interval [.25, .75]
# [1] 0.707403

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(ex.runif(1, .5, .25, .75), runif(1, min = .25, max = .75))
# Unit: microseconds
# expr         min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval cld
# ex.runif 692.439 704.685 721.51135 715.2735 722.9275 962.373   100   b
# runif      2.041   2.551   3.49044   2.8070   3.3170  21.176   100  a
```

Comment: return `q` after the loop

Comment: What is the motivation for this? In probability theory there is seldom any reason to distinguish between two random variables whose support differs by a set of measure zero.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm calculating a masked estimator from simulated data with probability _pi_. _pi_ is overlaid by an other value with probability _p1_ (which is drawn randomly in the simulation). Thus _p1_ `!=` _excl_, otherwise this would not be possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw random numbers from the mixture of uniform distributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34443195/draw-random-numbers-from-the-mixture-of-uniform-distributions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the set of values that you want to exclude is finite, then, in most cases, there is no need for a function like that. The reason is that the uniform distribution is continuous and any finite number of values are taken with probability zero. That is, `q == excl` is, in terms of probability theory, true with probability zero.

For instance,

```
set.seed(42)
ex.runif(5, .5, .25, .75)
# [1] 0.7074030 0.7185377 0.3930698 0.6652238 0.5708728
set.seed(42)
runif(5, 0.25, 0.75)
# [1] 0.7074030 0.7185377 0.3930698 0.6652238 0.5708728
```

The same is most likely going to happen under any other seed as well. Thus, you may just keep using `runif`.

@duckmayr makes a good point about numeric precision. In fact, as the interval `[min, max]` is getting narrower, `q == excl` becomes true with increasingly high probability and, in some applications, it may even become relevant.

However, if in theory you indeed need to exclude only a single value `0.5`, then performing a check like `q == excl` might even do harm by excluding unnecessary draws.

For instance, in my case `.Machine$double.eps` is 2.220446e-16. Then the probability of getting a draw from `[0.5 - .Machine$double.eps / 4, 0.5 + .Machine$double.eps / 4]` when `[min,max]` is `[0.5 - 10^(-k), 0.5 + 10^(-k)]` and making a false conclusion is 2 * (2.220446e-16 / 4) / (2 * 10^(-k)) or around 0.55 * 10^(k-16).

Comment: However, there is positive probability that a number is drawn within an (arbitrarily small) interval around 0.5; for example, within [0.5 - `.Machine$double.eps/4`, 0.5 + `.Machine$double.eps/4`] (particularly important since `0.5 == 0.5 + .Machine$double.eps / 4` returns `TRUE`). Of course, that probability is itself very small (about 0.00000000000000006 on my machine).

Comment: @duckmayr How do we calculate this probability?

Comment: `punif(0.5 + .Machine$double.eps/4) - punif(0.5 - .Machine$double.eps/4)`, which I would put through `sprintf()`: `sprintf("%0.17f", punif(0.5 + .Machine$double.eps/4) - punif(0.5 - .Machine$double.eps/4))`

Comment: A quick experiment to underscore how unlikely encountering 0.5 is: `x <- runif(10**8)` after which evaluating `which(x==0.5)` turns up no hits.

Comment: The restriction happens to be only harmful, if anything, because while `q == excl` might become true, it is going to be such for wrong reasons (with probability 1).

Comment: @Julius -- Good point. Of course, it will mean that for the OP, if they had a draw where `q == excl` returned `TRUE`, OP would *in effect* have a value in their data equivalent to the exclusion, so you'd have a problem whether you incorrectly discarded a value that falsely seemed equivalent to the restriction only because of numerical precision or if you correctly kept it, but from what you can measure, you'd have an impossible value in your data. This seems like a very unlikely problem, but one impossible to solve satisfactorily if it pops up.

Comment: Ok, I understand the math, Pr(q == excl) = 1/Inf -> 0. However I don't get it why e.g. excl == 0.5 could not be possible, isn't 0.5 an element of the uniform distribution? Besides `set.seed(42); x <- runif(5); set.seed(42); which(x == runif(5)[1])` returns `TRUE`. But ok—this convinces me somehow and since I can show on the quite low probability Pr(q == excl) I can consider this as a perfect answer for me. Thank you!

Comment: @jaySf, the fact that `set.seed(42); x <- runif(1); set.seed(42); x == runif(1)` returns `TRUE` (or the same thing with 5 numbers in my answer) is just a small example where your function doesn't have any effect. As for the probability, yes, 0.5 belongs to the support of the uniform distribution, just as well as a *continuum* of other numbers. I suggest to see answers like https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273382/how-can-the-probability-of-each-point-be-zero-in-continuous-random-variable or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-continuous-variable.

Comment: @jaySf A pseudo-random number generator is only a discrete approximation of a true uniform random variable. It only takes on finitely many values. It is possible that `0.5` is one of those values, though you would have to look into the details of the algorithm to see if it can actually happen. It *might* be the case that `0.5` isn't even in the range of `runif()` -- I don't know enough about the underlying implementation to say (though I suspect that it can pop up).

Comment: ...@jaySf, the point being that in the case of discrete random variables we are able to assign a nonzero probability for each possible value. So, in the case of a U[0,1] random variable X, if Pr(X = 0.5)=c>0, also Pr(X = x)=c for any x in [0,1]. But there is a continuum of such x and their "total mass" has to be 1! So, we get a contradiction.