# How to work/deal with open intervals of real numbers?

Tags: r, intervals

I'm often dealing with open intervals of **real numbers**, i.e. I want to exclude the borders, naturally to avoid `1/0:1` and these guys.

I helped me by writing this function,

```
oInt <- function(x, y, res=1) seq(x, y, res)[!seq(x, y, res) %in% c(x, y)]
x1 <- oInt(0, 1, .001)

> x1[c(1:2, length(x1)-1, length(x1))]
[1] 0.001 0.002 0.998 0.999

> sample(x1, 7, replace = TRUE)
[1] 0.703 0.404 0.698 0.287 0.753 0.679 0.354
```

but no matter how small `res=` is defined, it will stay an approximation. And it would use pretty much bytes saving such stuff this way I guess.

Then I came across the `sets` package:

```
> (x2 <- sets::interval(0, 1, "open"))
(0, 1)
```

E.g. this works not bad:

```
f <- function(x) x*x
curve(f, unlist(x2))
```

But e.g. this won't:

```
> sample(unlist(x2), 7, replace=TRUE)
lc rc  l rc rc rc  l 
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Is there a neat solution in (base) R that I have overlooked?  Maybe I'm not looking at the right places or am searching with the wrong words, but I found nothing. Or am I just on the [wrong track](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367150/6574038) again? ***Note:* For sake of scarcity I excluded other cases like e.g. half-open intervals, but of course I'm dealing with those too.**