# Comparing vectors when element close to zero

Tags: r, comparison

I would like to compare element wise between two vectors, but when the component is close to zero to get different what I expected.

Here is the code:

```
m <- rbind(c(-2.138697227039309,2.02792645210313,-0.0446693398025567)
            ,c(-1.963333204136506,2.50000000000000,-0.5366667958634941)
            ,c(-2.292730243327192,2.50000000000000,-0.2072697566728089)
            ,c(-2.525115170624692,2.43589709931669,0.0892180713080040)
            ,c(-0.736143506893788,2.50000000000000,-1.7638564931062122)
            ,c(-2.299960100106132,2.50000000000000,-0.2000398998938679)
            )
s <- matrix(c(0,5),nrow = 2)
A <- matrix(c(1,1,1,-1,1,-1),nrow = 2,byrow = TRUE)

for(i in 1:nrow(m)){
  cat("\niter #:",i,"\n")
  a <- A%*%m[i,]
  print(a)
  print(a <= s)
}
```

I get the following the output:

```
iter #: 1 
           [,1]
[1,] -0.1554401
[2,]  4.2112930
     [,1]
[1,] TRUE
[2,] TRUE

iter #: 2 
     [,1]
[1,]    0
[2,]    5
     [,1]
[1,] TRUE
[2,] TRUE

iter #: 3 
              [,1]
[1,] -7.771561e-16
[2,]  5.000000e+00
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,] FALSE

iter #: 4 
             [,1]
[1,] 2.026157e-15
[2,] 4.871794e+00
      [,1]
[1,] FALSE
[2,]  TRUE

iter #: 5 
              [,1]
[1,] -2.220446e-16
[2,]  5.000000e+00
     [,1]
[1,] TRUE
[2,] TRUE

iter #: 6 
             [,1]
[1,] 2.775558e-16
[2,] 5.000000e+00
      [,1]
[1,] FALSE
[2,]  TRUE
```

I expected different result in iterations 3,4 and 6.  Is there a better way to compare these vectors.

Here what I would like to have TRUE instead of FALSE

```
iter #: 3 
              [,1]
[1,] -7.771561e-16
[2,]  5.000000e+00
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE

iter #: 4 
             [,1]
[1,] 2.026157e-15
[2,] 4.871794e+00
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE

iter #: 6 
             [,1]
[1,] 2.775558e-16
[2,] 5.000000e+00
      [,1]
[1,]  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the expected output?  do you need `lapply(seq_len(nrow(m)), function(i) pmax(A %*%m[i,], 0))`

Comment: @akrun, thank you but this is not what I am looking for. I would like when the value of the A%*%m[i,] close enough to (0,5) to return TRUE instead of FALSE

Comment: Close enough means to `.Machine$double.eps`

Comment: the difference is still greater than `.Machine$double.eps`.  May be you need a different threshold

Comment: @akrun close enough to .Machine$double.eps or little smaller

Comment: How about `lapply(seq_len(nrow(m)), function(i) {a <- A %*%m[i,]; (a -s) <= (10 *.Machine$double.eps)})`

Comment: Possibly related (second part of answer): https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367150/6574038

Answer (score 0):

We can check whether the difference between 'a' and 's' is less than or equal to a multipliper of `.Machine$double.eps`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(m))){
   cat("\niter #:",i,"\n")
    a <- A%*%m[i,]
    print(a)
    print( (a -s) <= (10 *.Machine$double.eps))
}
```

Comment: what if I want to change the inequality to equality to check for the difference. How I would deal with values very close to zero, as such                                    
 for(i in seq_len(nrow(m))){
   cat("\niter #:",i,"\n")
    a <- A%*%m[i,]
    print(a)
    print( (a -s) == (10 *.Machine$double.eps))
}

Comment: @OlelDias  It can never be equal because they are floating numbers